# How to test the presence of environnements variables in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, automated-tests

**Question**

There are many ways to achieve that goal but I would like to know what is the best way to tests the presence of the environmental variables inside a Ruby on Rails project.

**Context**

We recently had a production issue related to a missing environment variable in one of our Rails project.

To prevent this from happening again, I would like to test the presence of the environments variable in the `application.yml` configuration file.

I am using Ruby 2.5, Rails 4.2, Spring 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless checking this specifically in `application.yml` is an absolute requirement (why?), here is my take. Make a `config/initializers/env.rb` and put in there something like

```
%i[FOO BAR BAZ].each do |var|
  ENV[var] = ENV.fetch(var)
end
```

What this does is reads all of your required environment variables (FOO, BAR, BAZ etc.) and [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) them which will 'raise' if this variable is not set at boot time.